# Which is the Best Client Side Scripting language with support for animations for web site development

Tags: html, web, client-side

I am new to Web Site development and have some experience in Application Development.

What i want to know is which Client Side Scripting language will be best for front end animations such as fade ins and fade outs, dialog box animations and page loading animations.

I need them to be very light weight as much as possible.

I have heard JavaScript provides is good for this but want other options as well.

Please suggest.

Comment: Javascript provides good stuff fot that, with lot of plugin (JQuery etc...), or Flash, maybe, for more improved animated stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript is good for this stuff, but if you what some more you can look into a library as JQuery. And for more animations and stuff maybe [JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com). Of course for basic animation you can use pure css and html5.(But only modern browsers support this.)

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks NatureShade..:)